# HTML client for cxf rest service with @HeaderParam & List<Attachment>

Tags: java, html, web-services, rest

I have cxf rest service with `@HeaderParam` and List Attachment as parameters. I have to create html client to invoke the service. Could anyone help me in how to set the headerparams because when I hit the service I get the following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: value can't be null for parameter param1
```

as this parameter is set `@NotNull`&`NotBlank` and is not able to find in the header.

Answer (score 0):

This exception because required header is not available as a part of HttpRequest header.

you have to cook-up your code to set the custom header. Something like below code, So that your REST resource will consume the parameter from incoming request header

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("Your URL");

//Adding custom headers
request.addHeader("HEADER_NAME", "VALUE");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

System.out.println("Http Response Code : " 
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gnana I have written this in main method and its working absolutely fine, but I need to use HTML as client so any other suggestion.

Comment: If it is a plain HTML, you can use html meta tag. But if you want to do it   in a dynamic way, you can use AJAX request.

Comment: Could you please provide with some example?

Comment: I tried adding in header `<META NAME="param1" CONTENT="12345">
  <META NAME="param2" CONTENT="45618">` but no luck.